# "Overloading" templated and non-templated types

Tags: c++

In c++, it is possible to overload a templated function such that it can be called with template parameters or without:

```
void func();
template <typename T> void func();

func();
func<int>();
```

Is the same possible for a Type (i.e., class)?

```
class Class;
template <typename T> class Class;

Class a;
Class<int> b;
```

I am only interested in being able to use both `Class` and `Class<T>` as types, where `Class` would behave identically to `Class<void>` - the declaration of the classes can be as complex as necessary to get this to work.

Comment: You could use default template arguments and leave it at `Class<>`. IMO, having it sometimes be a template could be confusing. I would think if the other syntax was possible, it would have been what was used for a defaulted one.

Comment: You can use `auto a = make_class();` vs. `auto a = make_class<int>();`

Comment: @dyp I actually like that rather well, especially since the class will be used frequently as an r-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a default argument.

```
template<typename T = void>
class Class;
```

`Class<>` is now equivalent to `Class<void>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would much prefer to be able to use simply `Class` rather than `Class<>`.

Comment: @zennehoy You cannot achieve that with either type or template aliases, because a single name cannot denote a type and a template at the same time. There might be a way out of this with macro hackery but I'd rather not go there.

Comment: Thanks - I feared as much, but figured I'd ask. Macro hackery is definitely not an option, so I guess I'll have to live with `Class<>`.